# Use rows from select result as columns in new declared table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement that returns a single column result table with a maximum of four results

```
Result
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

I need a new table as below

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

Looking this up before asking a lot of people suggest using Pivot but it seems like I need to know the results from the initial select statement which I don't in this case.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If there's always 4 rows, you can just use row_number to generate you 4 columns that you know (numbers 1..4), with something like this:

```
select * from (
select row_number () over (order by (select null)) RN, *
from (
  select 'aaa' as Result
  union all
  select 'bbb'
  union all
  select 'ccc'
  union all
  select 'ddd'
) X 
) S
pivot (max(Result) for RN in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) P
```

The result:

```
1       2       3       4
aaa     bbb     ccc     ddd
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3142)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```
select max(case when rn = 1 then result end) as col1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then result end) as col2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then result end) as col3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then result end) as col4
from
(select result,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
from TableA
) as A
```